# Vite can't build .graphql files from node_modules

Tags: node.js, vue.js, graphql, vite

I'm working on move my build from vue-cli to vite.
So I got problem with the package that contain part of my app code (package placed in `node_modules`). In this package I have *.vue and *.graphql files, like source code without any compilation. I import that files and with vue-cli it works well, but with vite i get error:

```
Error: Build failed with 17 errors:
ERROR: No loader is configured for ".graphql" files: node_modules/<path-to-file>.graphql
...
at failureErrorWithLog (node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1624:15)
at node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1266:28
at runOnEndCallbacks (node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1046:63)
at buildResponseToResult (node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1264:7)
at node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:1377:14
at node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:678:9
at handleIncomingPacket (node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:775:9)
at Socket.readFromStdout (node_modules/esbuild/lib/main.js:644:7)
at Socket.emit (node:events:513:28)
at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12)
```

Although, for my local .graphql files it works without any errors.

And maybe important thing - when I try to use `yarn link` for this package, it start to works! It's great but I can't use `yarn link` any time. It looks like bug of vite or maybe of the plugin `@rollup/plugin-graphql`.

`node v16.17.0 (npm v8.15.0)`

`vite.config.js:`

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import Vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue2';
import Graphql from '@rollup/plugin-graphql';


export default defineConfig({
    server: {
        port: 8011,
    },
    plugins: [
        Graphql(),
        Vue(),
    ],
});
```

```
vite: 3.0.9
@rollup/plugin-graphql: 1.1.0
@vitejs/plugin-vue2: 1.1.2
```

Comment: i have same problem!! i do npm run dev, with bash using git, and thats runs

Comment: I didn't solve it yet and just decided to build sources of package and use compiled version